# Error when requesting the last page of results.

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

When I try to view the following URL:

> http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions?page=93781&site=stackoverflow

I get the error:

```
{
  "error_id": 500,
  "error_name": "internal_error",
  "error_message": "this error has been logged"
}
```

Normally an invalid page returns an empty question set, not a 500 error. But this isn't even an invalid page. At the time of the request above, the API reports that Stack Overflow has `2813421` questions, so:

```
2813421 / 30 = 93780.7 (which rounds to 93781)
```

There should be a page 93781.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query backing that method, while not bad really, didn't look to be up to quite that much data/paging.

It's been replaced with a better query in the latest build, which should be plenty fast.